# Issues connecting Magento Cloud to Bitbucket

Tags: magento2, cli, magento-cloud

Following the [Bitbucket integration](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/integrations/bitbucket-integration.html) guide, I provided all the required permission to the Auth Consumer, and I log out and log in again with my Magento Cloud CLI, but even though I keep having this issue below.

[image: Magento Cloud Bitbucket Issue to connect]

#### Issue checking integrations

```
  [PermissionDeniedException]                                        
  Permission denied. Check your project or environment permissions.  
                                                                                                           
  [ClientException]                                                                                        
  Client error response [url] https://us-3.magento.cloud/api/projects/3gsageefda/integrations [status   
  code] 403 [reason phrase] Forbidden [message] Access was denied to this resource. [detail] {"error":"Un  
  authorized: collection_index_view failed permission check"} [title] Forbidden
```

#### Issue integrating the project

```
HTTP/2 403 
server: nginx
content-type: application/json
date: Wed, 28 Jul 2021 21:13:56 GMT
content-encoding: gzip

{
  "status": "error", 
  "message": "Access was denied to this resource.", 
  "code": 403, 
  "detail": {
    "error": "Unauthorized: collection_create_view failed permission check"
  }, 
  "title": "Forbidden"
}%
```

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This error message appears when the data are wrong or with wrong permissions.

Remove and create a new OAuth consumer and add the data again in your `bitbucket.json` file again.

[image: Magento Cloud Bitbucket integration]

After that, you just need to run the command again, you might be able to setup the integration with this command below too.

```
magento-cloud integration:add
```